# how to call onComplete() used with interval() in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm new with `rxjava`.

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8"
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

I'm working with `interval()`,

I don't know ***how to show View in `onComplete()` of rxjava without block UI Thread***.

Or ***call `onComplete()` from `onNext()`*** in below codes :

```
Observable
                    .interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(aLong -> {
                        Log.d("", "onNext()");
                    }, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> {
                        Log.d("", "onComplete()");

                        Log.d("", "SHOW POP UP");

                        showView();
                    });
```

People who know,

Please tell me,

Thank you,

Comment: Lambda passed in `#Subcribe` will get called on main thread because of `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`. So you can access UI element there .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code may work.

```
 Observable
            .interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
                
                Disposable d;
                
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    this.d = d;
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull Long aLong) {
                    if(!d.isDisposed()) {
                        this.onComplete(); // this will call onComplete()
                        d.dispose();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    showView();
                }
            });
```

Comment: can you help here -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63485056/share-image-from-url-to-other-apps